# Spring restTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, resttemplate

I'm trying to use spring rest template to do a post request to login in.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
mvm.add("LoginForm_Login", "login");
mvm.add("LoginForm_Password", "password");

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriDWLogin, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

all goes well, but when I try to send a second request, It generates an error saying :

> Business Manager closes your session after 15 minutes

And i need to know can i use the resttemplate to manage sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestTemplate never manages session, nor do any of the service because all of them are stateless. If you want to manage the state, what you can do is get the token first time and then pass that token each time to the next service call.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, how I could pass this token ? I tried to pass the headers and he didn't work.

Comment: create a map with all the keys and values you want to pass. After that create a HttpEntity object , set the headers and map to the entity object, pass this HttpEntity Object in place of the request Entity. This should work for you.